# 406 HTTP response in REST springboot service (XML)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson, jaxb, maven-plugin

I'm new to springboot development and JAVA, I'll be needing your help.

I have created a REST service using springboot to accept and produce message of XML format.
I have generated JAVA class files for XSD schema using JAXB plugin.

I'm able to pass the XML request to the REST service and display the values as well, but in response of service i'm getting 406 HTTP response.

I tried checking stackoverflow for any hint, i found that adding below dependency in pom will resolve the issue. When i added below dependency then i was able to get the proper XML response but then i was unable to get the input XML in the service, i want getting "NULL" object as input to service after adding dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Can you please help me and let me know how can i pass input XML request and get output XML response as well. Currently either one of the case is working for me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by adding  @XmlRootElement annotation in all the JAXB generated java class files.

Hope this will help someone!